# Traffic signal light in JS using array and conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I am trying to build a traffic signal light.

there will be a variable called signal where green, yellow, and red are stored as a value of that variable. If the traffic light shows red light, that means there is danger. If the traffic light shows yellow light, I should stop. If there is a green light, I can cross the road.

My code is :

```js
var signal = ["green", "yellow", "red"];

if (signal == "red") {
    console.log("Danger");
}

else if (signal == "yellow") {
    console.log("Stop");
}

else {
    console.log("Cross the road");
}
```

I am expecting, if I select one color, then it will show the only output as I mentioned previously

Comment: The question is lacking information. What exactly is the question? How are you planning on selecting the color?

Comment: you're comparing `signal`, which is an array of 3 strings to a single string. This won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You Code flow is not correct for solve your problem.

Array values are not required to check.

You simply check with if...else Condition.

```
// you can change value to get your results - "green", "yellow", "red"

var signal = "green"; 

if (signal == "red")
{console.log("Danger");
}
else if (signal == "yellow"){
console.log("Stop");
}else {
console.log("Cross the road");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `signal` has the value `["green", "yellow", "red"]` and since you don't change it ever, it can never be `"red"`, `"yellow"` or "`green`". One is an array of strings, while the other is just a string.

You are lacking a piece in your model, which is the current signal.

```
var signals = ["green", "yellow", "red"];
var currentSignal = "red";

if (currentSignal === signals[2]) {
    console.log("Danger");
}

else if (currentSignal === signals[1]) {
    console.log("Stop");
}

else {
    console.log("Cross the road");
}
```

But that's a bit hard to read, with indexing the array and stuff. And what if `currentSignal` is set to `"teal"`? So let's just refactor your signals into some sort of enumeration, or just a plain object:

```
var signals = {
  red: "red",
  yellow: "yellow",
  green: "green"
};

var currentSignal = signals.green;

if (currentSignal === signals.red) {
    console.log("Danger");
}

else if (currentSignal === signals.yellow) {
    console.log("Stop");
}

else {
    console.log("Cross the road");
}
```

In a simple scenario this would now suffice, but technically you could still assign `currentSignal` a value of say ... `""` or `"black"`, because javascript does not handle types very well, so you could (or should) add another condition:

```
var signals = {
    red: "red",
    yellow: "yellow",
    green: "green"
};

var currentSignal = "3 double whoppers";

if (currentSignal === signals.red) {
    console.log("Danger");
}

else if (currentSignal === signals.yellow) {
    console.log("Stop");
}

else if (currentSignal === signals.green) {
    console.log("Cross the road");
}
else {
    throw new Error("invalid signal detected");
}
```

And of course, depending on your preferences you also use a switch statement:

```
switch(currentSignal) {
    case signals.red:
    console.log("Danger");
    break;
  case signals.yellow:
    console.log("Stop");
    break;
  case signals.green:
    console.log("Cross the road");
    break;
  default:
    throw new Error("invalid signal detected");
}
```